# Can I install Call of Duty Advanced Warfare on external USB pen drive?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I'll buy *Call of Duty Advance Warfare* in the next days but I know there is a installation disk.
I want play ONLY the multiplayer online, not the campaign.
I need a HDD original from Microsoft, because I have the Xbox 360 with 4GB of memory.
Can I use an external USB pen drive? And if I want buy the DLC, can I install that on the USB pen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. If you want to play only multiplayer then you don't need to install anything.
You only need to install to play the campaign.

Now second of all. Yes you can use a USB, or a HDD. When you go into the storage settings of the xbox you will find your external USB there. There you format your USB to Xbox Memory format(You get to pick how much memory you use) and you can use it as a storage device.
Once you do that yes you can save DLC's on them too. But honestly fork out the 50 euro for a HDD!

Source: Ex-Xbox Ambassador and CoD AW Owner.

Comment: Why you suggest the HDD?

Comment: Cause you'll always run out of HDD space if you don't It's easier to save the annoyance of not having space and fork out 50 euro for a 50 euro standard HDD or 50 euro for a Xbox HDD

Answer (score -2):

It's like CoD Ghost, you need to install a content to play single player but for online you do not need to install anything, unless it is DLC content.